# unprintable string to number in python

Tags: python, string, printing, hex

The documentation http://docs.python.org/library/wave.html says

```
Wave_read.readframes(n)
```

> Reads and returns at most n frames of audio, as a string of bytes.

I want to see these string in hex or just number for knowing then value when no sound is there or plus, minus sound is there

I tried

```
import wave

target = wave.open('t2.wav')

length = target.getnframes()

section = target.readframes(2205)

print section[0:2]
```

this code print string looks like `+` and when I run the code,

```
print int(section[0:2])
```

Raises

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:/py/pitch2.py", line 5, in <module>

    print int(section[0:2])

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x10'
```

how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print [ord(i) for i in section[0:2]]
```

or

```
print [hex(ord(i)) for i in section[0:2]]
```